# Diagnose cause of a referential integrity error on a DELETE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting this error when performing a DELETE operation:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_GENERIC_ATTRIBUTES_PARENT". The     conflict occurred in database "DEV_CI", table "DOMAIN.GENERIC_ATTRIBUTES", column 'PARENT_OBJECT_REF'.

Is there any way of finding out the root cause of the problem i.e. the actual data?

Can SQL Server logging be enabled to highlight anything?

Comment: It tells you exactly what the issue is, there is a record in table `DOMAIN.GENERIC_ATTRIBUTES`, column `PARENT_OBJECT_REF` which refers to the record being deleted. What further diagnostics do you want?

Comment: Agreed - and If I was dealing with a small table I could run a select and work it out ...but this is a delete happening on many generic objects with many generic attributes - crazy generic database structure using 2 tables for multiple entities !

1000's of deletes happening here at a high level with lots of sub-objects ... hard to explain this - sorry !

It would be nice if an error was logged  with at least the actual data that caused the error as a clue.

Comment: Referential integrity is the last line of defence - its the job of your application to test that a record is in a fit state to be deleted. Regardless of table size you can still run a select to work it out.

Comment: Again I agree. But sometimes we are not masters of our own destiny.  An inherited system, with hierarchical generic DB tables ...
So I can't get a concrete value that the delete is failing on then ?

Comment: Certainly I don't know of anyway to determine that information after the event. Sorry

Comment: @NottmTony . . . In SQL Server, a single delete only affects a single table unless you have triggers on the table.

Comment: You could try setting up an extended event session to capture error_reported events and then search the captures for error_number = 547. This will return more than just failed deletes due to reference constraint violations, though, it also has inserts and updates due to constraint violations. Shouldn't be too hard to sort them out based on the sql_text.